# How exactly does J. J. Thompson's cathode ray experiment show that electrons are particles?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, electrons, atomic-physics

I've have heard in many places that J. J. Thompson used a magnet and capacitor plates to look at the effects of the electric and magnetic fields on the cathode ray. This way, he was able to deduce the electron-to-mass ratio $e/m$, and conclude that *if* the ray consisted of a stream of particles, *then* each particle in the stream is ~1000x lighter than the hydrogen atom.

My issue here is that I don't understand why his experiment demonstrates the existence of particles to begin with. Why couldn't the ray have consisted out of some "electric fluid" (like a continuous density distribution)? It seems like his conclusions are predicated on the supposition that the ray consists of particles (so we can't appeal to this experiment as a demonstration of electrons because it would be circular reasoning). Am I wrong here?

How does J. J. Thompson's experiment show that the electric rays in the cathode ray tube are made of particles? Do we need to appeal to another experiment (like the Millikan oil drop experiment)? Is there reasoning that deduces this *without* appealing to other experiments outside of the ones Thompson performed?

Comment: See https://history.aip.org/exhibits/electron/jj1897.htm

Comment: I guess one could conclude that the "fluid" was made into identical "drops" by the source so that they satisfy the various experiments, but then you are just back to identifying the "drops" as electrons.